# Do I need to implement my own RelayCommand if I want a sync command in ReactiveUI?

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm, system.reactive, reactiveui

I want to show a `straightforward dialog` window on pressing a `button`.

In case subscribing is the only option, my follow-up question is whether I need to do

```
.ObserveOn(RxApp.MainThreadScheduler)
```

on `commands` as well?

Answer (score 2):

Subscribing on the ReactiveCommand does sound like the most obvious choice.

`RxApp.MainThreadScheduler` is already the default scheduler for ReactiveCommands, as per the [ctor](https://github.com/reactiveui/ReactiveUI/blob/master/ReactiveUI/ReactiveCommand.cs#L325), if you didn't provide another scheduler there.

It'll be the `ObserveOn` context for your subscriptions.